# Anonymous Type where Properties are unknown until runtime

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I have the following scenario, I want to create a DataGrid and then populate the contents at runtime.

The issue I am having is that because I do not know what the fields are until I am creating the grid I do not know how to set the item source correctly. As you can see in the following code I am adding the Field names as columns, I am then looping through my items and at this point I want to create an anonymous type for each item where I am setting a property (called its field name) to the field names value

```
foreach (string fieldName in listViewFieldCollection)
{
    DataGridTextColumn newColumn = new DataGridTextColumn
                                       {
                                           Header = fieldName,
                                           Binding = new Binding(fieldName)
                                       };

    dataGrid.Columns.Add(newColumn);
}

List<object> list = new List<object>();

foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
{
    foreach (string fieldName in listViewFieldCollection)
    {
        list.Add(new
                     {
                         // I want to be able to dynamically build Anonymous type properties here
                         fieldName = listItem[fieldName]
                     });
    }
}

dataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
```

for example. If I have the Fields called 'Title' and 'Link' then I want the list.Add(new to behave as

```
    list.Add(new
                 {
                     Title = listItem["Title"],
                     Link = listItem["Link"]
                 });
```

but if the fields are 'Manager', 'Title' and 'Salary' it should perform like

```
    list.Add(new
                 {
                     Manager = listItem["Manager"],
                     Title = listItem["Title"],
                     Salary = listItem["Salary"],
                 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like using reflection could work.  The code below is something that may get you started.  The snippet will loop through all Properties on the object.

```
        foreach (var currentPropertyInformation in source.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if ((currentPropertyInformation.GetGetMethod() == null) || (currentPropertyInformation.GetSetMethod() == null)) 
                continue;

            if (string.Compare(currentPropertyInformation.Name, "Item") != 0) // handle non-enumerable properties
            {
                // place this snippet in method and yield info?
            }
            else // handle enumerable properties
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Fantastic, I will give this option a go as soon as I can and report back. Thanks @greglev

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible without reflection or codegeneration.

```
new
                 {
                     Manager = listItem["Manager"],
                     Title = listItem["Title"],
                     Salary = listItem["Salary"],
                 }
```

is converted to class with three fields and then few lines to set these fields. This is codegenerated by compiler. So in runtime you can't do that.